# Slow loading of combobox items with viewmodel

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, viewmodel, extjs5

My app has a form with three combobox.
The comboboxs stores are in a ViewModel.

```
 Ext.define('app.ComboboxsModel', {
 extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
 alias: 'viewmodel.comboboxsmodel',
 stores: {
        storeA:{
            model:'AModel',
            autoLoad:true,
            actionMethods:{
                    read:'POST'
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url:  'php/url',
                reader:{
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data',
                    successProperty: 'success'
                }
            }
        },

        storeB:{
            model:'BModel',
            autoLoad:true,
            actionMethods:{
                    read:'POST'
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url:  'php/url',
                reader:{
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data',
                    successProperty: 'success'
                }
            }
        },

        storeC:{
            ...
        }
});
```

It works. The data is loaded into comboboxs.

The problem is that the loading is very slow.
Data from the last combobox take about 5 seconds to load.

If instead of declaring the stores in viewmodel I placed the stores in the app store folder and reference them in Apllication.js file works as expected and faster.

However, I intended to use ViewModel.

Is there any way to load faster - or before load form - the stores (comboboxs items) with viewmodel?

EDIT:

Comboboxs Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/vqe

COMMENT:

Explain better the issue:

The problem is not at this stage, but when I edit a record in a grid and I want to load the record data in the form comboboxs (config 'name').

If the config valudeField 'name_id' is replaced by 'name' load faster, but still slow.

However, on the server side (PHP), for the comboboxs, I work preferably with ids (primary key).

```
name: 'name', 
displayField: 'name', 
valueField: 'name_id',
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with the problem? In our project we define all stores over VM and some of them contains over 10 stores, and they are loaded fast.

Comment: Thanks for answering yorlin. I note now that I did not explain well my question. Excuse me.I edited the code with a fiddle with various comboboxes that load well data from stores. See the comment too. The problem is not at this stage, but when I edit a record in a grid and I want to load the record data in the form comboboxs (config 'name'). If the config valudeField 'name_id' is replaced by 'name' load faster, but still slow.However, on the server side (PHP), for the comboboxs, I work preferably with ids.